# How to upload Multiple APKs(Same VersionCode) for Different API Levels IN PLAY STORE

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play, apk

I create two APK files from my Ionic Application for Different API Levels:

1. 1st APK for 19 to above API Levels
2. 2nd APK for 15 to 18 API Levels with Crosswalk-Webview Plugin.

I Google a lot, but I did't get a proper answer. If any one upload different  APK file for Different API Levels.

Please help me.

Comment: Google has an [entire page](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) on this subject. Among the things listed there is "Each APK **must have a different version code**".

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use same `VERSION_CODE` for multiple APKs in Google Play. To upload different APKs for different versions, set a lower `version_code` for the lower API (Android 15+), and higher `version_code` for higher API (Android 19+)

Comment: Thanks for reply Vlad, My main question is that Is it possible to upload multiple APK file for different level of Android API.

Comment: @Neotrixs, i wrote how to do it in answer

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation here https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

and here https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html

Also ensure you upload your APKs in **Advanced Mode**